# nested loop for matplotlib graph of financial time series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to print graphs for the selected tickers as I am learning python and matplotlib. I have written the following code and it works fine, except for the legend which prints the entire list of tickers, and I understand why it is doing that, but I don't understand how to get it to print only the ticker related to that graph. 
I also feel that as I am a beginner, I might have written too many lines of code, and if someone can guide me on how to reduce this code, that will help me learn the right way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

tickers=["ADBE","AAPL","GME","SNDK"]
roll_pd=30
num_std=2
flist=[]
ts_cutoff_days=-220
flag=1
start=datetime.datetime(2008,7,1)
end=datetime.date.today()

for ticker in tickers:
    time_srs=pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(ticker,start,end)
    #time_srs.head()
    fname=ticker+"_ohlc.csv"
    print (fname)
    time_srs.to_csv(fname) 
    flist.append(fname)

for fn in flist:
    #print(fn)
    df=pd.read_csv(fn,index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
    df.head()
    df.index
    close_px=df['Adj Close']
    ts=df['Adj Close'][ts_cutoff_days:]
    if flag==0:
        px_srs=close_px
    else:
        px_srs=ts

    mavg=pd.rolling_mean(px_srs,roll_pd)
    mstd=pd.rolling_std(px_srs,roll_pd)

    rets=px_srs / px_srs.shift(1) - 1
    rets.head()


    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(px_srs.index, px_srs,color='k',label=tickers)# this is where I am making the error
    plt.plot(mavg.index, mavg,label='mavg',color='red')
    plt.fill_between(mstd.index,mavg-num_std*mstd,mavg+num_std*mstd,color='b',alpha=0.2)
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.axes().yaxis.grid(True)
    plt.show()

if flag==0:
    df1 = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start, end)['Adj Close']
else:
    df1 = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo(tickers,start, end)['Adj Close'][ts_cutoff_days:]# I tried writing [ts] instead of ['Adj Close'][ts_cutoff_days:], but it gave me an error, so I had to write this above if-else condition to create df1 correctly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rather toss away your `flist`, as all the information is already in `tickers`.. Then you can do:

```
...

for ticker in tickers:
    df=pd.read_csv(ticker + 'ohlc.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
    ...
    plt.plot(px_srs.index, px_srs,color='k',label=ticker)
```

If you are worried about changing the file names, then you can create a simple function for that and use it in both reading and writing the file.

Another possibility would be to put a tuple into flist:

```
for ticker in tickers:
    ...
    flist.append((ticker, fname))
```

And then use this tuple in your next loop:

```
for ticker, fn in flist:
    ...
```

This also enables you to use `ticker` as the plot label.

Comment: I am afraid the `flist.append` as you've shown above doesn't work, I get an error.Does it work for you?

Comment: @user3766123: It should work, as it is just adding a tuple (ticker, fname) into `flist`. This line should replace the line `flist.append(fname)` in your original code (i.e. in the upper loop). If you still get an error message, please tell which one and on which row. Make sure you have the parentheses right.

Comment: fixed that. any suggestions on reducing the num of code lines

Comment: @User3766123: In python reducing the number of code lines is not the target :) With a very quick glance onto the code I have two questions: Do you really need the CSV files (if you don't do not create them, if you need, it is inefficient to reload the data which you just saved)? And why do you have two for loops looping through the same data? (It would make sense if you had defined functions into your code.) There are a lot of stylistic subtleties, but you will get probably the best answers by using the Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com And no, your code is not bad.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'll try to fix it. I didn't know there was a codereview site, I'll certainly use that

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set plt.title instead of label:

```
plt.title = ticker
```

[labels, annotations, etc](http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/text_demo_fontdict.html)

Comment: well, I want to change the label, not the title